# How exactly to save data in App Data Storage of applicationcraft?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile

I am newbie to Mobile development, I am using http://motech.applicationcraft.com/ to get some app going. I read about App Data Storage and wanted to use it to save some data.

I have done something like below.

[image]

3 text box with storage in d/b value TRUE.

Now I want on Click of Save button this 3 details gets saved.

My guess I need to write some Javascript on click of Save button, not sure how/what?

Comment: There is no need to clutter your title or question with excessive punctuation like `???` or `!!!`. Leaving that noise out makes your question easier to read, and adding it does nothing to help you get answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreference to store data in App.

Like..

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("name" valueOfName);
editor.putString("name" valueOfUserId);
editor.putString("name" valueOfPassword);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: how to use SharedPreference in applicationcraft?

Answer (score 0):

Pritesh
Internal storage in AC is deprecated so using d/b value= true will not do anything.
Store data securely into your own external database using Server Side functions (see [this link](http://www.applicationcraft.com/revisions/current/docs/user-guide/index.html?data_storage2.htm) )